# How can I clear bad shorcuts from GNOME Do cache?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shortcuts, cache, gnome-do

I am using Ubuntu and GNOME Do and have some bad shortcuts (they even have a grey X icon ) that I can't figure out and delete from the list.

I thought GNOME Do has some cache but its been a while and they are still there.

I deleted the `~/local/share/gnome-do` folder and still no success.

Any ideas how to clear them from the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you have created shortcuts by some menu/shortcut editor, in my case is `alacarte`. I found that when I remove shortcuts from menu by alacarte, it does not remove .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/` but only set flag `hidden=True` which gnome-do somehow does not recognize this so it still display that shortcut. So make sure that `.desktop` file was deleted along with removing `~/.local/share/gnome-do/` directory

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `~/.local/share/gnome-do/` directory worked for me, but you have to make sure you terminate gnome-do before doing so...

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me.

I found that deleting `~/.gtk-bookmarks` cleared them out.  It is where older versions of ubuntu/nautalus(?) stored your bookmarks.  However, after doing this I noticed that Gnome DO wasn't picking up my new shortcuts.  I had to add a symlink to the new location.

```
ln -nsf ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks .gtk-bookmarks
# => .gtk-bookmarks -> /home/[USER]/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a little bit a brute-force way to do it, but removing (renaming) the

```
~/.local/share/gnome-do
```

folder worked for me.

Comment: didnt work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I do not use personally gnome-do, but I found 
[How to clear the icon cache?](http://groups.google.com/group/gnome-do/browse_thread/thread/9a7db4f7c3d06de8) which says:

> When you change desktop files
>   (depending on how you do it) for some
>   reason, GNOME decides to keep  copy of
>   the old one around but just hide it.
>   Do sees both the old and new copies.
>   Delete the old ones and you should be
>   good to go.
>
> Culprit for me turned out to be in:
>   ~/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers

Comment: empty folder. tnx for the try

Comment: @solomongaby: What happens if you search for the old icons ? (I don't have DO or Gnome so can't do it.)

Comment: @solomongaby: Funny question - have you checked for hidden files in the above folder?

Comment: yes i did .. nothing in there

Comment: @solomongaby: Try to see if some hidden dir/file exists in $HOME.

Comment: `find "$HOME" -name '*.desktop'`. That will find everything that could possibly be a launcher anywhere in your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open `~/.local/share/applications/` and find files with error names (like your error). Delete them.

Restart gnome-do or the system.